# Inverse haversine formula - Change in geocentric coordinates from great circle distance and bearing?

Tags: kinematics, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, geometry, geodesics

I think this question best fits here - it's reasonably mathematical in nature, but is formulated as a practical kinematics problem; I'm happy to move it if I'm wrong. I'm trying to build a plane tracker, and the data I receive includes a set of geocentric coordinates (lat-long), a bearing from north, and a velocity, updating twice every second. I, however, would like to know the position at a more frequent rate that that for smoother tracking - not jumping at 0.5Hz - and so I'd like to interpolate the current position using the velocity, bearing and the time since the last position update.

Finding the great circle distance (i.e shortest distance between two points on a sphere on the surface of the sphere, measured along the surface of the sphere) between two sets of geocentric coordinates is easy to do with the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), with $\varphi_2$ and $\varphi_1$ as latitudes of point 1 and 2, and $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ as longitudes, and r as the radius of the earth (modelled as a sphere):

$$d = 2\cdot r\cdot \arcsin\left(\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac{\varphi_2-\varphi_1}{2}\right)+\cos(\varphi_1)\cdot\cos(\varphi_2)\cdot \sin^2\left(\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{2}\right)}\,\,\right).$$

However, I cannot seem to find or figure out how to do the inverse - from a heading and (approximating the straight line produced by integrating the velocity w.r.t time as great circle distance) great circle distance, calculating the change in longitude and latitude. It seems like a problem with a fairly simply spherical geometry solution - but I cannot work it out. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: This is probably more of a mathematics question than a physics question;  I've flagged it for possible migration.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a spherical triangle with three vertices:

- $A$, the aircraft's initial position
- $B$, the aircraft's final position
- $N$, the North Pole

The side lengths of this triangle are as follows:

- $\overline{AB} = d/r$, where $d$ is the distance traveled and $r$ is the radius of the Earth
- $\overline{AN} = \theta_1$, the initial colatitude of the plane (note that $\theta_1 = 90^\circ - \lambda_1$)
- $\overline{BN} = \theta_2$, the final colatitude of the plane

We also know that:

- The angle at $A$ is the initial heading of the plane, measured clockwise from north.
- The angle at $N$ is the change in longitude of the plane, $\phi_2 - \phi_1$.

From these considerations, it is pretty straightforward to apply the laws of cosines and sines to find $\theta_2$ and $\phi_2$, assuming $\theta_1$, $\phi_1$, and $d$ are known.  I believe the quickest way is to find $\theta_2$ first using the law of cosines, and then use the law of sines (along with your result for $\theta_2$) to find $\Delta \phi$.